# The maximum nametable character count quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. - ASP.Net MVC to Dynamic CRM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

The maximum nametable character count quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. The nametable is a data structure used to store strings encountered during XML processing - long XML documents with non-repeating element names, attribute names and attribute values may trigger this quota. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxNameTableCharCount property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 1298.

How to fix this error?? When I'm saving data to CRM I'm getting this error.

This my function in saving

```
     public void SaveAccount(ParentModel objAccountModel)
    {
        using (OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService("MyConnectionString"))
        {
            Guid? accountid = null;

            if (objAccountModel != null)
            {
                Entity accEntity = new Entity("account");
                accEntity["name"] = objAccountModel.Customer.Company;

                accountid = service.Create(accEntity);

            }

        } 
   }
```

My connection string in web config

```
 <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Url=https://makeademo.crm.dynamics.com; Username=asin@makeademo.onmicrosoft.com; Password=aaaaa;" />
```

Controller (apsp is  my model)

```
  DAL_AccountEntity objDAL = new DAL_AccountEntity();


            objDAL.SaveAccount(apsp);



            return View(apsp);
```

Comment: any update if you have resolved this issue?

Comment: I just used my previous solution before that is working. I just abandoned the new solution, so i don't know if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once. In my case it was a problem with not compatible SDK ( I was using older SDK than CRM version I was connecting to). Check the version of the CRM you are connecting to (CRM 2016 is version 8.x, CRM 2015 is version 7.x, CRM 2013 is 6.x etc.) and make sure that in your asp.net website you are using SDK libraries from the same version.